# Powershell - Check if path is root or subfolder?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a Powershell script (with the help of someone here, thanks!) that is writing values to an xml to compare with another xml at a later time.

The important command is here that is outputting data to be compared:

```
'RelativePath' = ($file.fullname.substring($BaseDirectory.Length))
```

$file is for filenames being analyzed in a for loop through recursive subdirectories.

$BaseDirectory is the starting folder to begin analyzing

'RelativePath' resolves the folder path properly and starts with a leading "\" if it's a subdirectory (i.e. C:\Temp). But if it's a root path (i.e. just C:) it stores the path without the leading "\".

For example, running script with `$BaseDirectory='T:\'` output would look like this (reference "RelativePath"):

```
-<Obj RefId="2">
   <TNRef RefId="0"/>
  -<MS>
      <S N="Hash">F13B655DEC0C07ACFD9329CB250276A3</S>
      <S N="FullPath">T:\20200412_193057\Public\Terraria\Jim's_wolrd.wld</S>
      <S N="FileName">Jim's_wolrd.wld</S>
      <I64 N="Size">11387570</I64>
      <S N="RelativePath">20200412_193057\Public\Terraria\Jim's_wolrd.wld</S>
   </MS>
 </obj>
```

but with `$BaseDirectory='Q:\Archive'` the output would look like this (again reference "RelativePath"):

```
-<Obj RefId="2">
   <TNRef RefId="0"/>
  -<MS>
      <S N="Hash">F13B655DEC0C07ACFD9329CB250276A3</S>
      <S N="FullPath">Q:\Archive\20200412_193057\Public\Terraria\Jim's_wolrd.wld</S>
      <S N="FileName">Jim's_wolrd.wld</S>
      <I64 N="Size">11387570</I64>
      <S N="RelativePath">\20200412_193057\Public\Terraria\Jim's_wolrd.wld</S>
   </MS>
 </obj>
```

Only difference being "RelativePath" has the leading "\". So when I'm comparing the two, they aren't equal because of that leading path back slash (or lack of it).

Comment: Always specify `BaseDirectory` with a trailing slash, then your RelativePath values will uniformly _not_ start with a slash.

Comment: /Facepalm/ Thanks. That seemed to do the trick... sigh.

Comment: Why "sigh"? If that's a workable solution, I'll post it as an answer & you can mark it as 'Solved'.

Comment: @KeithMiller Thank you. "sigh" was for me. It was a simple solution that I just missed. It worked. If you want to post as answer I'll be glad to mark as solved.

Comment: Cool. Thought that might be the case, but wanted to make sure. And actually, if you test various forms of relative paths, they should start with either a folder/file name or `.\ `. A relative path beginning with a slash, i.e. 'sl \foldername`, will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths for folders/directories can be specified with or without a trailing slash. If you always define **BaseDirectory** with a *trailing* slash:

```
$BaseDirectory = 'T:\'
$BaseDirectory = 'Q:\Archive\'
```

Then your string manipuation will always return a **RelativePath** that begins with the file/folder name, *not* a slash.